# How to create a functions py and call those functions?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyramid

I am practicing with Python using Pyramid framework.

I created a py, `myfuncs.py`, in my main package folder where there is also a Views folder with `views.py` inside and Models folder (models inside) along with other folders for static files and templates (as created by Pyramid scaffolding).

I want to define functions and classes within the myfuncs.py located at the myproject package root and then access them from within any of the views and models located in their respective views and models folder.

How can I achieve this? I try importing but it won't work.

Comment: -1 " I try importing but it won't work." This means nothing. Show your code, and the error.

Comment: Seriously? You want to see "import myfuncs"? What code are you talking about? That's what I am enquiring in the question.

Comment: @Phil no, Marcin wants to see the code of your `myfuncs` module and the error message you are getting.

Comment: brandizzi, I am not having issues with my code. My code is a 2 line test function. I am asking to figure out how to call that or any functions which exist in a separate py file dedicated to hold these arbitrary functions which are there to be shared and called by multiple modles and views. The part I am failing is IMPORT part because it is not importing anything as it is not recognising the function names in the myfuncs.py

Comment: @Phil If the only line of code you have is `import myfuncs`, then you can't be having problems calling functions in `myfuncs`. I suggest that you take your question to a psychic engineering consultancy who won't need to see your code to debug it.

Comment: Marcin, in my question I clearly state that I want to call the procedures defined in myfuncs from views which are within the views folder.

Comment: @Phil Yes, you clearly state that, which suggests that there is more than one line of code, which you are not showing us. Pay for some psychics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

imagine this structures of folders and files:

```
MyFuncs (folder)
    __init__.py (can be completely empty)
    utilFunctions.py
    genericFunctions.py
    uselessFunctions.py
    Views (folder)
        __init__.py (again!!)
        views.py
```

Now you can "import" the folders (in reality you import  __ init __.py using the folder name, but this is for now a detail)
Be sure to have the PYTHONPATH properly set.

for example:

```
import MyFuncs.utilFunctions
from MyFuncs.Views import views
import MyFuncs.uselessFunctions as nonsenseFunctions
```

etc.etc.

That __ init __.py must be in any folder you wish to import

Within views.py you simply do:

```
from MyFuncs import utilFunctions

utilFunctions.aFunctionYouCode()
```

Comment: Dear Dan Niero, thank you! from ProjectFolderName import PyFileContainingFunctions did the trick. Thank you very much!

Comment: glad to have been useful. Everything will become clear after a little while. I remember to have had the same trouble when I first start to code in Python.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have an `__init__.py` in the root folder, and import it with:

```
import functions
```

Then you should be able to call the functions with `functions.<functionname>()`

Comment: My myfuncs.py is in the main folder where there already is the main __init__.py I did try this but it is not working.

Comment: You can also try to add #!/usr/bin/python to the top of your file. I remember having that issue, and that worked for me.